# How to get name from another table when ids match?

Tags: mysql, variables, match

Well, I suck in here (although I'm trying to learn). I can't understand how to improve my code when I see when others answer similar question to my (I know it might duplicate) and at the moment I'm stuck at my last step finishing php file. I have a tables called "cities" where there are columns called "id" and "name" and another table called "locations" where there are columns "id" and "location". I also have code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM locations"; 
$res = mysql_query($query); 
while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
 echo '<b>'.$arr['id'].'</b><b>'.$arr['location'].'</b>';
}
```

While my code works and I get id of wanted ID, I need to get name of city and not id. IDs in both tables match. I cannot edit tables or columns. What should I add? Can it be solved without any left, join, in, etc. queries? I can't understand them despite how I'm trying...

Comment: You need a JOIN, or another query. So, once you get the id, you can't issue another query to lookup cities by the same id?

Comment: @EdvinTenovim Have you checked my answer below?

Comment: Can you share the structure of your tables please?

Comment: @hex494D49 here: http://i.imgur.com/uQU7CZL.png other table 100% fine because there are more queries that interact with it. This one is new.

Comment: Well, can you update your question and add a few records from both tables, 'cause this looks fine

Comment: Oh, God, I finally made it!! I have last question but it's not that important. How to separate two different IDs while both are used in same query? (Like SELECT x FROM xx where id = "$row["cid"])." | But I also need for $row["lid"]).

Comment: @EdvinTenovim You're not reading me; in order to help you I need to see your tables. Otherwise, take a look at my answer and you'll see how to distinguish two columns with the same name from two different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT l.id, c.name 
    FROM locations AS l
    INNER JOIN cities AS c ON c.id = l.id
");

while($l = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo '<b>' . $l['id'] .'</b><b>' . $l['name'] . '</b>';
}
```